# argparse add_argument alias

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to create an alias using argparse?

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo' ...)
parser.add_argument_alias('--bar', '--foo')
```

That is, using `--bar` should be equivalent to using `--foo`.

Comment: Does `parser.add_argument('--foo', '--bar', ...)` work?

Answer (score 32):

You can simply call:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', '--bar', ...)
```

at least for Python 3.5.

This is how I tested it in `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import argparse

In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [3]: parser.add_argument('--foo', '--bar')
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo', '--bar'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [4]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO'])
Out[4]: Namespace(foo='FOO')

In [5]: parser.parse_args(['--bar', 'FOO'])
Out[5]: Namespace(foo='FOO')
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you asked for, but when you want to alias a *key-value* combination instead, as in `--bar` should be equivalent to using using `--foo=baz`, you can use the `dest` parameter:

```
parser.add_argument('--bar', dest='foo', action='store_const', const='baz')
```