# Aliasing commands in Python Argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like some of my argparse commands to have an alias.

For example, let's say I have the command `mycli test --true posarg`. In this example, `mycli` is the name of the program (the parent parser), `test` is a subcommand (subparser parser), `--true` is a boolean flag argument, and `posarg` is a positional argument.

I would like to keep it this way, but also have some alias `mycli true-test posarg` that points to the definition of `mycli test --true posarg`.

I would like to do this without setting an os-level alias in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [argparse add\_argument alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896992/argparse-add-argument-alias)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi No – that's just for arguments under a command. Using my example from above, that would help if I wanted `mycli test --true` to be the same as `mycli test --vrai`

Comment: What is this `test` and `true-test`?  A positional argument?  or a `subparsers` `parser`?

Comment: To minimize confusion in questions like this, it's a good idea to include the `argparse` setup code, at least as far as you've gone.  It's much easier to suggest improvements to existing code.

Comment: I realize now how my question is unclear, and I've edited it so hopefully it is clearer now @hpaulj

Comment: As shown in @chepner's answer, 'true-test' has to have its own definition.  It can set the same attribute(s), but it's too different to be a simple  alias.

Answer (score 0):

Not an alias in the sense that you define one command that refers to another, but you can define two separate subcommands that achieve the same result. One has an option `--true`; the other has a positional argument with the same name.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = p.add_subparsers()
p1 = sp.add_parser("test")
p1.add_argument("--true")

p2 = sp.add_parser("test-true")
p2.add_argument("true")


print(p.parse_args())
```

Then

```
$ python3 tmp.py test --true 3
Namespace(true='3')

$ python3 tmp.py test-true 3
Namespace(true='3')
```